# Select  elements by CSS property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select DOM elements by their CSS property?

For example:

```
awsome_function ({'background-color' : '#0cf'});
// return all object, which's background-color css attribute value is '#0cf'

awsome_function (['background-color']);
// return all object, which has background-color css attribute 

awsome_function (['-my-special-cssattribute'])
// return all object, which has '-my-special-cssattribute' css attribute
```

I know that it is possible to select elements using the jQuery `each` method, like this:

```
$('*').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('-my-special-cssattribute')) {
      /* do something */
   }
})
```

However it's maybe slow and unelegant. Is there a cooler way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a custom selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    foo: function (e) {
        return $(e).css('background-color') == '#0cf';
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
alert($('div:foo').size()); //get the count of all the divs that matches the selector
```

Comment: i love it. Is there any way to parametering that 'foo' ? forexample $('div:foo("background-color", "#0cf")')

Comment: @NagyMárton I would suggest keeping that kind of logic inside the function that returns the elements that you need. Use `&&` if you want to add more conditions

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to append different classes with different background-colors. Then you could select those.

Or you could try .css()
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: thx for the answer but i want to use some kind of fast filtering, for a global fallback library. forexample, i added a -spec-border-radius css property, it call a method which add rounded corner for that object in any browoser.

Comment: I don't think doing it this way is a pretty solution. Mozilla, Webkit and IE9+ have border-radius and if you want it for IE 8 you would have to use images.

Answer (score 0):

> > However it's maybe slow and unelegant. Is there a cooler way to do that?

It is slow. It is unelegant. Don't do that. Select your elements with an ID or *eventually* with a class, but never that way. Seriously.

Comment: should clearly point out that both selecting by class and/or CSS property will make jQuery parse the whole DOM tree. (in most browsers) the only *direct* (means: fast) selector supported by all JS implementations is the ID selector.

Comment: Which is why "eventually" is in italic :-). But for his case, selecting all the elements by class would be a good idea (supposing that the class adds a background).

Comment: I agree with what you say but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think it does. He wants to do something very specific. I answer that he *definitely* must not do it.

Comment: thx for the answer, i just want to create a fast automatic css3 fallback lib, and there is no way to use classes / ids sorry.

Comment: Then don't use jQuery. Use vanilla JS if you want *fast* :-).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - so he wants to build a Chrome extension that shows a 'wireframe' of his site, i.e. removes the colour from coloured divs and add a border. He can't do it because you say so?

Comment: @hooleyhoop: seeing the context of this question, it is clearly not the case :) browsers' extension are a special kind.

Answer (score -2):

Answer : There is no way to do that, and for good reasons.
It'll be very slow, and it is of course worse than unelegant.

Personnaly, if i one day see one of my devs do that, i'll kill him and/or ask my boss to replace him immediately.

Use classes or much bettern ids ! If you can not, the problem comes from your application structure logic.